# R markdown eval function doesn't work anymore - problem with duplicate labels

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, eval

I hope somebody can help me with the problem I'm having.
For my work, I am writing a report in R markdown. This R markdown is pretty future prove, like there are multiple code chunks, each with their separate eval-function, which produces only 1 correct table. A correct table depends on if some variabeles which need footnotes, are present in the dataset or not. The R markdown worked 2 or 3 weeks ago, but now when rendering the R markdown script it gives the following error:

```
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.scr,
markdown_mode): 
Duplicate chunk label 'name of the label', 
which has been used for the chunk: (chunk is shown).
```

The name of the label is used in 12 different chunks, but only 1 of the 12 chunks should be activated by the 12 different eval statements. Somehow, that doesn't work anymore. I have manually changed the eval-statements to 11 times 'FALSE' and 1 time 'TRUE' but it produces the same error. The error is gone when, of course, only 1 chunk is present and the rest is deleted but I need the multiple/different chunks.

Example of how I set up the eval-statements (in R markdown):

````
```{r}
if (exists("footnote") &
    all(dataset$number_tested.x >99) &
    all(dataset$antibiotic %notin% c("gentamicin", "amoxicillin"))){
  eval_option1 <- TRUE} else {eval_option1 <- FALSE}

if (exists("footnote") &
    all(dataset$number_tested.x <100) &
    all(dataset$antibiotic %notin% c("gentamicin", "amoxicillin"))){
  eval_option2 <- TRUE} else {eval_option2 <- FALSE}

if (!exists("footnote") &
    any(dataset$antibiotic %in% c("gentamicin")) &
    all(dataset$antibiotic %notin% c("amoxicillin"))){
  eval_option3 <- TRUE} else {eval_option3 <- FALSE}

```
````

How the eval-statements are used:

````
```{r, table_label, eval=eval_option1}
Set-up for producing table option 1.
```

```{r, table_label, eval=eval_option2}
Set-up for producing table option 2.
```

```{r, table_label, eval=eval_option3}
Set-up for producing table option 3.
```
````

And so on. When everything is done, I remove the variables that aren't needed.

````
```{r, remove}
rm(dataset, eval_option1, eval_option2, eval_option3)
```
````

Deleting the remove-part out of the R markdown doesn't solve my problem. And of course, removing these variables didn't cause any trouble 2 or 3 weeks ago.

Does anyone know what can cause this problem? Is it a render() problem (so in the rmarkdown package)? Is it a knitr package problem? Has 1 of these packages recently been updated which need an updated R program version? Is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are giving them all identical chunk names? Is there a reason they have a chunk name at all? Packages won't update on their own, that's a manual process. Have you updated/installed any packages lately?

Comment: This script has to work for different countries and each country has different information in their dataset then others. There is also a possibility that next year some information is present which is not present this year. So I have made every possible version of 1 table that could be produced, each with different kable() settings.
My work environment didn't work as it should be a couple of weeks ago. I can't remember if the script didn't work while the work environment didn't work well, or if the script didn't work anymore after I've accidentally updated the packages during that time.

Comment: Hmmm, based on the info you've given, can I suggest naming each chunk differently? e.g. {r, table_label, eval=eval_option1} -> {r, table_label1, eval=eval_option1}; {r, table_label, eval=eval_option2} -> {r, table_label2, eval=eval_option2}

Comment: At first, that wasn't an option. I refer to those tables in text so they need the same name. However, I make my captions in a different script instead of in the R markdown itself, and I have found a colleague that uses the following script in her own captions (also in a different R script): str_c("\\label{tab:table_name}[rest of the caption"). That works for me too and now I have different chunk names like table_label1.

Still, it is weird that something that works before doesn't work now. That is still a mystery for me and my colleagues.